# Visualising sharing settings, roles and rights

Tags: settings, sharing, roles

A little about our platform;

We have events that are part of calendars (1 or more). Calendars can then be added to a user dashboard. That user dashboard can have many members part of it. (Owner, members, viewers)

E.G - Events can be made public, totally private only (only the owner), shared with individuals and shared with groups (each one of these can be given certain rights - edit, view, delete)

It is a very complex, secure system but obviously it is quite difficult for our users to wrap their heads around what and who things are shared with.

I'm trying to work out the best way to go about visualising this. Of course, I first turned to google to see how they perform in this. Google drive is the closest application I could think of with a sharing settings area. However, it isn't quite as complex as ours as not very applicable.

**My question is;**

If there are other examples out there of complex sharing setting applications out there that I can look at and learn from.

Comment: are calendars fixed ? meaning.. are there only set number of calendars you work with or does that change (Add/remove?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try taking a look at the sharing options for Google Drive items and Dropbox items.

Google drive allows for full sharing, view only, and view and add comments - It also allows for sharing between individuals, groups, and the general public.

From memory I think Dropbox has a fairly similar system to the Google setup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I made a sample design.. let me know if this handles, if not you can tweak it or expand on it.

[image]